# Receive Nodejs events in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, events

I am working on a project that will use React as my client and Nodejs as my server. My design is that the Nodejs server will listen to some external data streams, process the data, save the data in MongoDB and then emit some events to React. The server-side code is like

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://someurl');

ws.on('message', (data) => {

    ........

    /*
        preprocess and do the mongodb stuff
    */

    myEmitter.emit('someevent', data)});
});
```

My question is, how can I listen for such an event in my React client? If I stick with this approach, do I need to pass in `myEmitter` to my React components?

I am new to React so please let me know if there is any better way to solve the problem.

Comment: If you use `socket.io` you can just set up a listener on the client side.

Comment: @Colin What if I have hundreds of data streams to listen to? Would I need to manually type in equal amounts of server endpoints in my React components?

Answer (score 2):

> do I need to pass in `myEmitter` to my React components?

no... your client side and serverside code should be separate. You can use a client-side SocketIO app like socket.io.

if you're going to be listening for a bunch of different events in different components, consider using an `enhancer` style wrapper

```
function withSocket (event?, onEvent?) { // note: this is TS
  return (Component) => {
    class WithSocketEvent extends Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        this.socket = io.connect(SOCKET_ENDPOINT)
      }

      componentDidMount () {
        if (event && onEvent) {
          this.socket.on(event, onEvent)
        }
      }

      componentWillUnmount () {
        this.socket && this.socket.close()
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <Component
            { ...this.props }
            socket={ this.socket }
          />
        )
      }
    }

    return WithSocketEvent
  }
}

// usage

class HasSocketEvent extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    // handle the event in the component
    this.props.socket.on("someEvent", this.onSocketEvent)
  }

  onSocketEvent = (event) => {

  }

  render () {

  }
}

// handle the event outside the component
export default withSocket("someEvent", function () {
  // so something
})(HasSocketEvent)
// or
export default withSocket()(HasSocketEvent)
```